# How do you mark a Ruby Binding as trusted?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, trusted

From this article http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/erb referring to thread safety levels:

"At this level, the specified binding must be marked as trusted for ERB to use it."

I've searched high and low and haven't found a way to "mark" a Binding as "trusted".

Will somebody please enlighten me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should **taint** the binding by calling the `taint` method.

The `$SAFE` levels are a feature of Ruby that denies certain actions depending on the current level and whether an object is **tainted**. Tainted strings are assumed to originate from an untrusted source, such as a file, a database, a HTTP client, etc.

At `$SAFE` level 1, for example, Ruby will not allow you to `require` files if the argument is a tainted string.

`$SAFE` level 4 is the most extreme. Ruby will effectively disallow you to modify **any nontained** object. The idea is that you can use a lower `$SAFE` level in your application, and instantiate a thread or proc with `$SAFE` level 4. Within this **sandbox**, you can modify **tainted** objects only.

ERB uses this mechanism to allow you to run a template within a sandbox. If you try to get the result of a rendered template from a certain binding, this is what happens:

```
class TemplateContext
  def name; "Teflon Ted"; end
end

template_binding = TemplateContext.new.send(:binding)
ERB.new("Hi, <%= name %>!", 4).result(template_binding)

#=> SecurityError: Insecure: can't modify trusted binding
```

**Blam!** This is Ruby telling you that it is **not okay to modify a nontainted** object at `$SAFE` level 4. It will not allow you to call `eval` with the given binding (which is exactly what ERB attempts).

Instead, you should provide the sandbox with a **tainted** binding. You are explicitly telling Ruby that it is okay to use this binding in a sandbox, and that it should not be trusted outside the sandbox.

```
class TemplateContext
  def name; "Teflon Ted"; end
end

# Binding must be tainted!
template_binding = TemplateContext.new.send(:binding).taint
ERB.new("Hi, <%= name %>!", 4).result(template_binding)

#=> "Hi, Teflon Ted!"
```

For more information about Ruby's `$SAFE` level, see the [excellent description in the Pickaxe book](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/taint.html).